# Products per row catalog

Tags: magento2, catalog, products

How to change number of products per row. I have been google but all the examples reflecting the way in magento 1.*

Comment: Did you check for the backend options for the catalog? Otherwise it might have to do with your theme (if you're using a custom one).

Comment: I use a custom extended from lumen

Comment: can u please instruct me how to do this inside theme?

Comment: well, I don't know about this specific theme, but I guess there should be a menu on the left when you enter System > Configuration

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a custom theme, for mobile view, my requirement was to show two products in a row.
 I just widened the li product-item and this worked for me.

```
>ol.product-items{
    >li.product-item{
        border:@border-1;
        width: 45%;
    }
}
```